# Extjs err:'0.manager.zseed' is undefined

Tags: extjs, window

When I close the Ext.Window,and then I create a new Ext.Window,I got a error:'0.manager.zseed' is undefined. However,This problem only occurs in IE 8.

code:

```
var win = new Ext.Window({
                                id: 'winBLNo',
                                title: 'myWindow',
                                width: 360,
                                height: 120,
                                layout: 'fit',
                                items: [formGetBLNoRule],
                                closeAction: 'close',
                                buttonAlign: 'center',
                                buttons: [
                                    {
                                        text: 'OK',
                                        handler: function() {}
                                    },
                                    {
                                        text: 'Exit',
                                        handler: function() {
                                            win.close();
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            });
                            win.show();
```

Help me pls. Thanks a lot.

Comment: what is `formGetBLNoRule`?

Comment: It's a simple form which contains a comboBox.However,This problem only occurs in IE

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming here that your using Ext JS 4 and that this window is a floating component.  If so, your problem lies with the Z-index.  Try setting this explicitly and that should solve your problem.